# paypal refreshing issue when goto checkout

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1, paypal, paypal-express

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Claxs.png)I am new to Magento 2.1.

I have an issue related to **paypal**.

when I am going to select payapal radio button and enterPlace order the product for payment and hit the paypal button then it will refreshing the page and redirect to checkout page.

Comment: Did you checked with log files for the error if not then check and please post your log file error related to paypal for better understanding.

Comment: maybe it is the magento developer mode

Comment: you change the production mode t working

Comment: how to change it

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html

Comment: in which directory to chnage it?

Comment: Done From My side